# using datediff in entityframework entity-sql

Tags: entity-framework, entity-sql

I want to do something like this using EntityFramework entity-sql query. I am using .Net3.5

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder(@"
                Select VALUE o
                From ordercontainer.report as o
                WHERE o.xId = @xId
                ");

query.Append("  && datediff(hh,getdate(),o.StatusChangeTimeStamp) >= @DurationInHours");
```

Comment: maybe you can use this object `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions`

Comment: thanks allo.. but that class is there from .net4 onwards... am using .net 3.5 framework..

Answer (score 0):

Use this method in .NET 3.5

```
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.DateDiffHour(startDate, endDate);
```

[See msdn site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495790%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

This class contains several more Methods that can be used in .NET3.5